# Copy and Rename Config File in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have specific config files for specific environments (dev,qa,uat) and another root web.config. The deployed code reads web.config. So I've been trying to either copy the contents or rename the file in Azure Pipelines.

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Copy Specific Config'
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: 'Client.WebApi.Core/Configs/Web.QA.config'
        TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\MainWebApi'

- task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: rename $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\MainWebApi\Web.QA.config 
        $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\MainWebApi\web.config
```

Another method:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          copy-item -path Client.WebApi.Core/Configs/Web.QA.Config -destination Client.WebApi.Core/web.config
          TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/MainWebApi'
```

I have tried various combinations like renaming then copying and copying and then renaming it, copying the contents into new web.config files etc
What exactly should be used?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic

Comment: Hi, is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know whether my anwser helps.

Answer (score 11):

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Copy Specific Config'
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: Copy-Item -Path "Client.WebApi.Core/Configs/Web.QA.Config" -Destination "$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/MainWebApi/web.config"
```

This a pretty straight forward way to achieve what you want. You could even make the environments (dev, qa, uat) dynamic in the Destination path if you like.

Comment: I have an artifact that gets produced by the CI pipeline and I have a release pipeline that has an Azure App Service Deploy stage that consumes the artifact. Lets suppose the name of the artifact is "Release". I want to include Library secure files in the artifact prior to the App Service deployment, but there's a catch: one of the secure files should be renamed to `private.key`. is this the write way to perform the copy after secure files are downloaded? `Copy-Item -Path "$(DocuSignPrivateKey.secureFilePath)" -Destination "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Build Artifact/Release/private.key"`

Comment: here's my post for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70073266/how-to-propagate-files-from-library-secure-files-through-pipeline

Comment: @Cataster checkout the answer I have provided. Let me know how it goes

Comment: I'd recommend this solution as it also overwrites an existing file.

Answer (score 9):

Did you try

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: ren $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\MainWebApi\Web.QA.config 
    $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\MainWebApi\web.config
```

You can follow these documents:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#where-can-i-learn-windows-commands
- https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html

Comment: I used the following steps:  1.delete the original file 2.copy the new file 3.then rename it. That worked for me. Thanks for help.

Comment: `ren` didn't like if you pass the path to the second parameter. So I think the proper use of ren would be: `ren $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\MainWebApi\Web.QA.config web.config`

Answer (score 2):

> What exactly should be used?

You can use the built-in task called [File transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic) to transform web.< environment >.config to web.config. And then, you can use "Copy files" task to copy web.config to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`.

Here are detailed steps:

Step1. You need to add a transform file, which is in the same path as the source file.

If you don't want to make any changes to result file, just create a xml file with one line of scirpt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

If you want to make some changes, write the changes in the transform file. Here is an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#xml-transformation-example).

Step2. In your pipeline, search and add a "File Transform" task.

[image]

You need to tick the "XML transformation" and  in "Transformation rules", write foolowing script:

```
-transform {transform file} -xml {source file} -result Web.config
```

Step3. Search and add a "Copy Files" task. Copy Web.config file to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`.

Here is the yaml script for step2 and step3.

```
steps:
- task: FileTransform@1
  displayName: 'File Transform: '
  inputs:
    folderPath: '{folder path}'
    enableXmlTransform: true
    xmlTransformationRules: '-transform {transform file} -xml {source file} -result Web.config'
    fileType: xml
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '{folder path}'
    Contents: Web.config
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\MainWebApi'
```