# How to propagate files from Library Secure files through pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a CI/CD pipeline that currently generates an artifact and the release pipeline propagates the artifact throughout nonprod and eventually prod stages.

The developer added some secure files to the Azure pipeline “Library” and would like to automatically include these files as part of the deployment. Currently he has to keep uploading them every time the release pipeline runs as it overwrites existing artifacts with the new artifact build.

Additionally, one of the secure files (Test-DocuSign-private.key) should be renamed to “private.key” (whether before/after deployment, whatever is more reasonable).

What tasks can achieve this (i.e. pulling the secure files from the Library and propagating them as part of artifact deployment)

[image: prop]

Here’s my App Service Deploy YAML and the download secure file and powershell tasks I added as prototype to what I'm trying to accomplish (Note the Copy download secure files and copy tasks).
Is this the right way to add (copy) the secure files to the CI Build Artifact that was produced (called Release) before the Azure App Service Deployment?

```
steps:
- task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@4
  displayName: 'Replace tokens in **/Web.config'
  inputs:
    rootDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Build Artifact/Release'
    targetFiles: '**/Web.config'
    tokenPattern: custom
    tokenPrefix: '<mailSettings>'
    tokenSuffix: '</mailSettings>'
    
steps:
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: GoogleServiceAccountKey
  inputs:
    secureFile: GoogleServiceAccountKey.json
    retryCount: 2
    
steps:
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: DocuSignPrivateKey
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'Test-DocuSign-private.key'
    retryCount: 2

steps:
- powershell: |
   #Copy GoogleServiceAccountKey.json file
   
   Copy-Item -Path "$(GoogleServiceAccountKey.secureFilePath)" -Destination "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Build Artifact/Release/GoogleServiceAccountKey.json"
   
   #Copy and rename *Env*-DocuSign-private.key file to private.key
   
   Copy-Item -Path "$(DocuSignPrivateKey.secureFilePath)" -Destination "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Build Artifact/Release/private.key"
  displayName: 'Copy Secure Files to Release Artifact'
  
steps:
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: ee-dev'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Azure Dev Service Connection'
    WebAppName: 'ee-dev'
    packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Build Artifact/Release'
    enableCustomDeployment: true
    RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: true
    AdditionalArguments: '-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath="Web.Dev.config|Web.Test.config|Web.Prod.config|Web.Sandbox.config|Web.Beta.config|\\*.zip" -retryAttempts:6 -retryInterval:10000'
    enableXmlTransform: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work provided you are running on a windows agent. You should however be mindful of the path separator "/" on windows.
I would rather use the more generic task which can run on any agent. Adding link here for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
    #Copy GoogleServiceAccountKey.json file
   
      Copy-Item -Path "$(GoogleServiceAccountKey.secureFilePath)" -Destination "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Build Artifact/Release/GoogleServiceAccountKey.json"
   
   #Copy and rename *Env*-DocuSign-private.key file to private.key
      Copy-Item -Path "$(DocuSignPrivateKey.secureFilePath)" -Destination "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Build Artifact/Release/private.key"
  displayName: 'Copy Secure Files to Release Artifact'
```

Comment: Thanks Heyman! I got this working yesterday using pretty much the identical code here, however, I had an issue with the secure file path. Consider my download secure file task: `steps:
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: GoogleServiceAccountKey
  inputs:
    secureFile: GoogleServiceAccountKey.json
    retryCount: 2` despite the name being `GoogleServiceAccountKey` this didnt work: `$(GoogleServiceAccountKey.secureFilePath)`. Instead what worked was `$(Agent.TempDirectory)/GoogleServiceAccountKey.json`. Also what'd you mean by: `the more generic task`, what task?

Comment: @Cataster It was because you used `-powershell` in your code, so I suggested you use the `Powershel@2` task instead so that it can run on both windows and linux agent. That way, it is more generic.

Comment: yes it can @Cataster haha. Enjoy

Comment: I always tried avoiding script tasks because I didnt want it to be OS constrained, but this just blew my mind! My love for powershell grows more and more everyday LETS GOOOOO

Comment: btw, I was trying to read this `/Build Artifact/` dynamically into the script, so I found `release.PrimaryArtifactSourceName` would return the name. However, powershell was not liking it `release.PrimaryArtifactSourceName' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file`. Is there a way i can make this work? I tried defining a variable and setting it to `env:release.PrimaryArtifactSourceName` but even as env variable it didnt work.